# Inorder traversal of 3-ary tree

Tags: tree, heap, tree-traversal

I recently came across a question. The question stated that a max heap is implemented using a 3-ary tree. Print the inorder traversal. I am confused whether it is left-child, parent, 2nd child , right child or left-child, 2nd child, parent, right child. Which one is it?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: This page gives traversal only for binary tree. I want it for a 3nary tree

Comment: Is that the entire question? "Print the inorder traversal of a 3-ary tree?" Depth-first traversal of an n-ary heap is kind of uncommon because the output is pretty much meaningless. A breadth-first traversal provides more meaningful information. But if you want to do "inorder", you get to define the order in which child nodes are visited.

Comment: This question was asked in a company recruitment test. A tree 3nary tree was given. Question was what is the inorder traversal. 4 options followed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the left and right part of the node children, depending on the problem you solve. Both of your suggestions are possible.

See more at:
[In-order tree traversal for non-binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778489/in-order-tree-traversal-for-non-binary-trees)

Comment: This answer should be a comment.